# css not working but style="" is

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why this is not working? I already used CSS validator and HTML validator and both passed

header.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a id="logo" href="index.php"><img src="includes/images/crown-automotive.jpeg" alt="Crown Cars World"></img></a>

        <div id="ownerLogin">
            <a href="ownerPage.php">owner login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.css

```
#logo
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is your `header.css` stylesheet being loaded in the browser?

Comment: Please search harder here or elsewhere for hints about how to solve this. The most likely problem is that the CSS file cannot be found, which the network tab of devtools will help you track down.

Comment: Thanks you too, I actually found out this problem only exits in chrome on linux. When I tried a different browser it works, now I just have to decide if I'll find out why or just leave it as a bug. Problem (more or less) resolved

Comment: @DréEllis are you hosting the files on a webserver or running them locally?

Comment: @Michael I am still building it so it's on localhost currently

Answer (score 0):

make sure your header.css and html file are the same folder. just check your css file path.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your page -> Inspect element -> select Network tab. Now refresh your page and see if header.css file is found or not. ( If it's not found, it will be highlighted in red color ) 
If that's the case , make sure you give the right path ( as mentioned by the others )